ArgoCD does not install helm chart dependencies
I am struggling to install a helm chart which has dependencies using ArgoCD.
I can install the helm chart without any issues using helm install ....
But it seems like ArgoCD just ignores the dependency of the helm chart completely.
I have searched for this a lot, but nobody seems to have an issue (unless a condition is used for dependency, which i am not using).
Some more details:

my chart is a std helm 3 chart that lives in a private repo that uses no authentication (i can install a chart from the same repo if the chart has no dependencies)
my chart (and dependent) chart has helm (pre-install) hooks defined (which according to argocd docs are supported)
again according to argocd docs the helm hook-weight is preserved which i need

This is the Chart.yaml of the base chart (that i depend on):
apiVersion: "v2"
name: "base-chart"
version: "1.0.0"
appVersion: "1.0.0"

This is the Chart.yaml of the actual chart:
apiVersion: "v2"
name: "app-chart"
version: "1.0.1"
appVersion: "1.0.1"
dependencies:
- name: "base-chart"
  version: "1.0.0"
  repository: "https://<my-private-repo>/repository/<repo>"
  alias: "base"

This is the argocd application manifest:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    name: myapp
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "1"
spec:
  project: default

  sources:
    - repoURL: https://<mynexus.com>/repository/<repo>/
      targetRevision: 1.0.1
      chart: app-chart

  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: myapp

Here are the details of the argocd installation:
[root@kubernetes1 mydir]# argocd version
argocd: v2.12.1+26b2039
  BuildDate: 2024-08-16T17:01:06Z
  GitCommit: 26b2039a55b9bdf807a70d344af8ade5171d3d39
  GitTreeState: clean
  GoVersion: go1.22.6
  Compiler: gc
  Platform: linux/amd64
argocd-server: v2.12.1+26b2039
  BuildDate: 2024-08-16T16:42:13Z
  GitCommit: 26b2039a55b9bdf807a70d344af8ade5171d3d39
  GitTreeState: clean
  GoVersion: go1.22.4
  Compiler: gc
  Platform: linux/amd64
  Kustomize Version: v5.4.2 2024-05-22T15:19:38Z
  Helm Version: v3.15.2+g1a500d5
  Kubectl Version: v0.29.6
  Jsonnet Version: v0.20.0

I could not find any related error messages on argocd application-server and repo-server logs or on the argocd ui. The application syncs correctly and appears in sync. However the resources from the dependent chart are nowhere to be found.
Appreciate any help or pointers. I am really stuck.
I am new to argocd, but feel like this should be one of the most basic scenarios, i mean to install a helm chart (with dependencies), no?

Did you make sure that the version and the repo url is correct? Try installing the dep using helm command to check if it works first.Also I think you have not given the path in sources.

Yes they seem to be correct. I can install the chart with helm without any issues. I tried to repackage and everything. No luck so far. I didn't put "path" intentionally, because the docs said it was ignored for helm repos and that "chart" needed to be used.

thanks for the help. i am ashamed to admit that the problem was caused by a .helmignore file on the app chart which caused resources from the base chart to be completely ignored :( the problem has obviously nothing to do with argocd, it can deploy charts with dependencies without any issues, even if those charts have helm hooks.

No shame in this, we all have done this. Im glad it worked out.

Try adding this hook to the application resource:
    syncPolicy:
      automated:
        prune: true
        selfHeal: true
      hooks:
        - type: PostSync
          command: ["helm"]
          args: ["dependency", "update"]


Nice. Will try. But one question: if i use any argocd hooks, the docs claim that all helm hooks will be ignored. My charts have helm hooks that are kind of important. Do you think this can be an issue? Thanks

This is an ArgoCD hook.
Argo runs helm template to render manifests from the chart. It is up to helm to execute its own hooks.

helm template renders the Helm chart templates to YAML manifests without applying them to the cluster, and it does not trigger Helm hooks.
Helm hooks: These are executed during Helm's lifecycle operations like helm install, helm upgrade, and helm delete, but not during helm template.
Therefore, when ArgoCD uses helm template to generate manifests, it does not execute any Helm hooks.

thanks for the help. i am ashamed to admit that the problem was caused by a .helmignore file on the app chart which caused resources from the base chart to be completely ignored :( the problem has obviously nothing to do with argocd, it can deploy charts with dependencies without any issues, even if those charts have helm hooks.

How did it work using helm install?

Not completely sure, i had the same question but when i retried with helm it worked indeed (with the incorrect .helmignore). I have then checked the helm version and the one i had installed (3.6.1) was very old compared to the much newer (3.15.2-...) one that the fresh argocd installation was using. My understanding is that helm started respecting .helmignore more strictly somewhere in between these releases.

The problem was caused by a .helmignore file on the app chart which caused resources from the base chart to be completely ignored :(
The problem has obviously nothing to do with argocd, it can deploy charts with dependencies without any issues, even if those charts have helm hooks (that are supported by argocd).
Make sure to check .helmignore files if you encounter similar issues.
